# (HANA SQL) Show multiple values in one row

Tags: sql, datetime, pivot, aggregate-functions, hana

I am trying to complete the following:

**Old situation**

[image]

**What I want**

[image]

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/Is-Pivot-available-in-SAP-HANA

Comment: have a look at [this](https://blogs.sap.com/2019/04/21/how-to-pivotunpivot-in-sap-hana/) for dynamic pivoting.

Answer (score 1):

For a fixed maximum number of target columns, you can use window functions and conditional aggregation:

```
select customer,
    max(case when rn = 1 then order_date end) as order_date_1,
    max(case when rn = 2 then order_date end) as order_date_2,
    max(case when rn = 3 then order_date end) as order_date_3
from (
    select t.*, row_number() over(partition by customer order by order_date) rn
    from mytable t
) t
group by customer
```